# Can SO be made responsive on desktops?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, design, user-interface

I have been browsing the Stackoverflow site on my Firefox browser of my desktop system, and when i resized my browser, the site is not getting adjusted automatically (non-responsive).

[image: Stackoverflow site on my desktop browser]

While i browsed the site on my Android, the site looks perfectly responsive, with good UI.

Just curious to know why Stackoverflow was not made responsive for the desktops, by default.
Because there are many responsive HTML frameworks available today like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Less](http://lessframework.com/) and [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/).

Is there a plan for implementing this feature in the future?

Comment: Well, i found my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210511/should-stack-overflow-be-redesigned-with-a-responsive-layout.